# Unique Validation In Broadleaf

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, e-commerce, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to add a unique validation on a field while adding a product on Broadleaf. Currently we have added a 'SKU' field while adding product from admin screen. I have used the following annotation to validate:

```
@AdminPresentationMergeOverride(name = "userSku", mergeEntries = @AdminPresentationMergeEntry(propertyType = PropertyType.AdminPresentation.VALIDATIONCONFIGURATIONS, validationConfigurations = {
                @ValidationConfiguration(validationImplementation = "blUniqueValueValidator", configurationItems = {
                        @ConfigurationItem(itemName = "otherField", itemValue = "userSku") }) })
```

It works perfect when we try to add a new product.
But the problem is, If I try to update any product to change any field, it gives the same validation error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that doesn't work quite right, can you open an issue in https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/Issues?

You can also write your own uniqueness validates that does not run into the same ID problem like so:

```
@Component
public class MyUniqueValueValidator implements PropertyValidator {

    protected static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(UniqueValueValidator.class);

    @Override
    public PropertyValidationResult validate(Entity entity,
            Serializable instance,
            Map<String, FieldMetadata> entityFieldMetadata,
            Map<String, String> validationConfiguration,
            BasicFieldMetadata propertyMetadata,
            String propertyName,
            String value) {

        String instanceClassName = instance.getClass().getName();
        DynamicEntityDao dynamicEntityDao = getDynamicEntityDao(instanceClassName);
        List<Long> responseIds = dynamicEntityDao.readOtherEntitiesWithPropertyValue(instance, propertyName, value);

        String message = validationConfiguration.get(ConfigurationItem.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        if (message == null) {
            message = entity.getType()[0] + " with this value for attribute " +
                    propertyName + " already exists. This attribute's value must be unique.";
        }

        boolean onlyInCurrentEntity = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(responseIds)
           || (responseIds.size() == 1 && responseIds.get(0).equals(getDynamicEntityDao(instanceClassName).getIdentifier(instance)));
        return new PropertyValidationResult(onlyInCurrentEntity, message);
    }

    protected DynamicEntityDao getDynamicEntityDao(String className) {
        return PersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(className).getDynamicEntityDao();
    }
}
```

And then use the validator by passing in the bean ID to the `validationImplementation`:

```
@AdminPresentationMergeOverride(name = "userSku", mergeEntries = @AdminPresentationMergeEntry(propertyType = PropertyType.AdminPresentation.VALIDATIONCONFIGURATIONS, validationConfigurations = {
            @ValidationConfiguration(validationImplementation = "myUniqueValidator", configurationItems = {
                    @ConfigurationItem(itemName = "otherField", itemValue = "userSku") }) })
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help looks like I dont have all the broadleaf methods which you are calling. I am using 4.0.5 version. For eg there is no method dynamicEntityDao.readOtherEntitiesWithPropertyValue and so on. What needs to be done in this case?

Comment: At least could you let me know the logic behind the code?

Comment: Is your entity sandboxed?